# Kernel Panic while booting Ubuntu 12.04 in Live USB

Tags: 12.04, kernel, live-usb

I get a kernel panic while booting Ubuntu 12.04 as a Live USB on two different computers.

One computer is custom made with Intel Processor Pentium Dual 1.8GHz with EM64T and an NVIDIA GPU card. The other is a Toshiba A200 laptop with Intel Duo Dual 2.0GHz and an ATI GPU.

I'm really good at Ubuntu. I start using it in 2010 with Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the md5sum for the ISO you downloaded:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

If you've got the same thing happening with two computers there's a good chance that the problem is that the ISO file got corrupted during download.

Chris

Comment: @Alexander You could also run the `Check disc for defects` option available in the menu when your Live USB is booted. Press any key when the [Ubuntu Live CD/USB 'small logo'](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tSYiR.png) appears to display the menu.See also the [*Ubuntu CD/USB Boot Options Page*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Ubuntu_CD_Advanced_Welcome_Page_Options).